# php-fpm process continuesly "execution timed out"

Tags: php

i set request_terminate_timeout = 30 in php-fpm.conf, also set max_execution_time = 30 in php.ini flie. Now there are some php-fpm not exit in 30s.Here are part of the php-fpm log:

```
child 136923 started
child 136923, script '/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") executing 
too slow (4.922829 sec), logging
child 136923, script '/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution 
timed out (30.265825 sec), terminating
child 136923, script '/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution 
timed out (35.600981 sec), terminating
....
child 136923, script '/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution 
timed out (88.958490 sec), terminating
child 136923 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 23586.510130 seconds from 
start
```

Here is my php-fpm.conf

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 250
pm.start_servers = 100
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 200
pm.max_requests = 2048
request_slowlog_timeout = 4
request_terminate_timeout = 30
security.limit_extensions = .php .html
```

why it continuesly "execution timed out"? when this happend, the cpu load is high.
BTW, i do not set fastcgi_keep_conn on in my nginx.conf, but i set default_socket_timeout = -1 in php file. Can be this the reason?

Comment: I guess you are confused between php terminate and process exit.

Comment: @shingo yes, you are right, but now i not confuse that, i just modified my question, please check :)

Comment: `index.php` contains an SQL query which takes too long to execute.